# How does Return 1 or -1 works/means in array.sort (a>b) (JS)? Asking about process of the methos array.sort

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I can't figure out what return 1 or -1 means in array.sort in js.

```
    const hola = [0, 4, 10, 60, 5]
const holaSorted = hola.sort(function(a,b) {
    if (a>b) {
        return -1;
    } else {
    return 1;
  } 
});
console.log(holaSorted);
```

console.table(holaSorted);`

[60, 10, 5, 4, 0]

Comment: It's explained pretty well here: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) starting with the bulleted list `If compareFunction(a, b) is less than 0,...`

Comment: There is a nice description on the `MDN`: [Array.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Description). However, note you need to return `0` when `a === b` too.

Comment: It doesn't have to be -1,1 and 0, it's `<0` `>0` && `===0`..  So your above example could just be `return b-a;`   eg.  `hola.sort((a,b) => b-a)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting an array of JavaScript objects by property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-javascript-objects-by-property)

Comment: @ctt Where does that question explain this?

Comment: @Barmar several answers to the linked question explain how `Array.sort()` is intended to be used with varying degrees of detail.  Some also link to the documentation, which provides even more clear explanations.  It is very likely that the answers to this question will be virtually identical to the linked question's answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of, as discussed above the [MDN Sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) description is very good.

But we can simplify for here:

When we call `sort` it allows us to provide a `function` to evaluate two `elements` of the `array` at any given time.

The `function` should return:

- a `negative` value if `a < b`
- a `positive` value if `a > b`
- and `0` if `a === b`.

The `sort` function will then use that value to order those two elements respectively.

```js
// Number ordering is very straight forward. 
const hola = [0, 4, 10, 60, 5]
const holaSorted = hola.sort((a,b) => a-b); 
console.log(holaSorted);

// reverse the order.
const holaSorted2 = hola.sort((a,b) => b-a);
console.log(holaSorted);
```

But not everything is a simple number, often we want to sort objects, this is where it becomes more important to provide a custom evaluator.

Below we sort using `name` and we need to pass back `1 || -1 || 0` based on a string compare.

```js
const people = [
  {
    name: 'Bob',
    age: 20
  },
  {
    name: 'Anne',
    age: 50,
  },
  {
    name: 'Terry',
    age: 5
  }
];

// Order by name
const byName = people.sort((a,b) => (a.name < b.name) ? -1 : (a.name > b.name) ? 1 : 0);

console.log(byName);

// Order by age
const byAge = people.sort((a, b) => a.age-b.age);

console.log(byAge);
```

Comment: Thanks you so much @Bibberty!!! Tell me if im fine with logic: `const byName = people.sort((a,b) => (a.name < b.name) ? -1 : (a.name > b.name) ? 1 : 0);` if a.name<b.name so a.name-b.name is a negative value. But what happend if i write this: `const byName = people.sort((a,b) => (a.name > b.name) ? -1 : (a.name < b.name) ? 1 : 0);` How im telling throgh the code that this is ¡ a desending order and not an asending?? P/D: Sorry for my basic english.

Comment: Think in simple terms the the `-1` and `1` are used to move `A` left or right of `B`